# Windows 10 x64 not Recognizing USB Bluetooth Dongle

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I'm using a Kinivo BTD-300 Bluetooth 3.0 USB dongle so I can use my DualShock 3 controllers wirelessly. To do this, I had to replace the original driver for the device (the Bluetooth driver that come pre-installed with Windows 10) with an ScpServer driver using a program called Zadig.

This is what I did to replace the driver: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuxXUKN1vz8

It was working fine for a few weeks, but after I changed the port the controllers weren't connecting properly. So I replaced the drivers again. Then when I plugged it in I got the notification saying "USB Device Not Recognized (Code 43)" no matter which port I put it in. Once in a while it would show up in "Devices" with an error code 10 (driver error).
I tried a System Restore from a few days ago, but now when I plug/unplug the dongle nothing happens. It doesn't show up in device manager and no notification pops up.

Also, the PC won't boot with it plugged in. It'll freeze at the "Press F2 to enter BIOS" screen, and won't resume until I unplug the dongle. Also, if I'm in the BIOS and I plug it in, it freezes up until i unplug it again. However, once booted into Windows I can unplug and plug it without freezing.
How can I fix this? Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the dongle is defective?

Comment: It was working before, so I don't think it's the dongle. I think it's a driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have BTD-300 and windows 10. I was having the same issue as your with the message "USB Device Not Recognized (Code 43)". The way to fix the problem is:

1. Go to **Power options** using the search bar
2. Click on **Change plan setting**
3. Then click on **Change advanced power setting**
4. Scroll down to to **USB settings**
5. And change it to **Disabled**

Hopefully that fixes your problem.